# Booting back to Ubuntu after Fedora installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bios

I can't boot into my Ubuntu OS(Partition /dev/sda2)after installing Fedora(/dev/sda4) and am getting that error message after choosing Ubuntu.

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me some time ago, using different distro. In my case it was problem in mounting wrong partitions.

Can you tell me if you have also windows installed?(Ubuntu may then mount wrong partition(hibernated ntfs win partition).

Solution:

1. Create Ubuntu/linux live usb & boot into live session.
2. Go into Ubuntu's partition and check in /etc/fstab for errors on that partition ( e.g. /media/Ubuntu/etc/fstab) . Maybe fstab file makes Ubuntu mount the wrong partitions. Learn about fstab on google.

If that does not work there may be problem with fedora's grub.

Boot into live-usb linux session and try 2 things (if one doesnt work, restart and try another):

1. in terminal run :
   `sudo update-grub`
2. Try to "brute force" it with boot-repair. Go in Ubuntu and run commands, and choose recommend repair. And hope it helps.

You can also try this. As soon as you turn the computer on press esc or del to choose from uefi menu (I do not mean grub menu, I mean BIOS-UEFI menu) what to boot, and choose Ubuntu (this will maybe open the old Ubuntu's grub.

Comment: @zanna, i have tried checking the fstab conf file and here is what it showing: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6p8ak6mm0lebg6w/AABwWIR2c0Y200Wv7GNIZgOXa?dl=0 and the partition with Ubuntu which is failing to login in the media folder i can only see the Fedora directory. Any idea of what I need to do with fstab file? Thank you

Comment: type `sudo blkid` in terminal and compare output against fstab UUID entries if they are the same. But I think they are good.